# Crystal reports - connection to JDBC failed

Tags: jdbc, crystal-reports, invalid-argument

I am trying to make a connection to JDBC(JNDI) in Crystal Reports and I get the following error :

Invalid Argument provided.
Details: Java Server startup failure. Please verify the PATH (JDK), CLASSPATH and IORFileLocation properties in the CRConfig.xml file. In addition, please verify you are using JDK 1.4.

I am using the connector : mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar, jDK 1.6.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the problem!
The directory associated to IORFileLocation (which is C:\Windows\temp for me) was for some reason readOnly.
So, problem fixed.
Thank you, anyway!

Comment: I had the same batch of error messages.  In my case it was the presence of some ampersand-separated parameters in my jdbcurl default value.  Those doh! need to be &amp;  not &

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. but this solution doesn't seem to help me.. anything else worth a try?